# Separating multiple value numbers (with characters) and text

Tags: r, excel

I have a file in Excel that has, as an example, text such as this "4.56/505AB" in a cell. **The numbers all vary, as does the length of text**, so the text can be single or multiple characters, and the numbers can contain characters such as a decimal point or slash mark.

The ideal, separated format for this example would be: column 1 = 4.56/505, column 2 = AB.

What I've tried:
"Split_Text" in Excel, which removed the special characters from the number, and resulted in the following output: column 1 = 456505, column 2 = ./AB

R with the "G_sub" command, which resulted in: [1] " 4 . 56 / 505 AB"

Is there a way to take these methods further, or will this be a manual fix? Thank you!

Comment: you need to use `strsplit()` in r.

Comment: There are a variety of functions in packages such as `stringr` that can help you with that, apart from `base R` solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first uppercase letter is the beginning of the second column

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c("4.56/505AB", "1.23/202CD"))

library(stringr)
df$c2 <- str_extract(df$c1, "[^[A-Z]]+")
df$c3 <- str_extract(df$c1, "[A-Z]+") 

df
#           c1       c2 c3
# 1 4.56/505AB 4.56/505 AB
# 2 1.23/202CD 1.23/202 CD
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) sub/read.table** Match the leading characters and the trailing characters within the two capture groups and separate them with a semicolon. Then read that in using read.table.  No packages are used.

```
x <- "4.56/505AB"
pat <- "^([0-9.,/]+)(.*)"
read.table(text = sub(pat, "\\1;\\2", x), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE)
##         V1 V2
## 1 4.56/505 AB
```

The result has character columns but if you prefer factor then omit 
the `as.is = TRUE`.  Also we have assumed there are no semicolons in the input but if there are then use some other character that does not appear in the input in place of the semicolon in the two places where semicolon appears.

**1a)** If we can assume that the second column always starts with a letter then we could just replace the first letter encountered by semicolon followed by that letter and then read it in using read.table.  This has the advantage of using a slghtly simpler pattern.

```
read.table(text = sub("([[:alpha:]])", ";\\1", x), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE)
```

**2) read.pattern** Using the same input `x` and pattern `pat` it is even shorter using `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = x, pattern = pat, as.is = TRUE)
##         V1 V2
## 1 4.56/505 AB
```

**Update:** revised.